# how to run a specific command via a bash script and add in to a startup

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

I want to execute this command in Ubuntu 14.04

`sudo ./crclient -u username -i eth0`

I will use it for login in cyberrom client. So need some help to create a bash script and add in to a startup like windows startup.

Comment: quick question, does the user need to input his/her own username?

Comment: yes its required

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Sure I am waiting for your post  :)

Comment: is it ok if the program runs in a terminal?

Comment: Yes its ok for me I just want to login through command and add into a startup

Comment: there you go, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you want to make in a shell script.

`#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter your username and press enter: "
read name
sudo ./crclient -u $name -i eth0`

in ubuntu open dash (the ubuntu button) and type startup

[image]

then you get this:

[image]

Press add and type at the command rule:

incase of the ubuntu terminal
`gnome-terminal -x "sh /path/to/script.sh"`

incase of xterm (which i prefer)
`xterm -e "sh /path/to/your/script.sh"`

then reboot and see if it works :)

**---------------------------EDIT---------------------------**

make a new file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`
using nano/vi or a text editor and name it test.dekstop

copy this into it

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyScript
GenericName=test
Comment=test
Exec=/path/to/my/script.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

reboot the pc afterwards

**______________________EDIT 2______________________**

To allow the command to run without sudo asking for a password, do the following:

`visudo`

scroll all the way down and add this

`linuxusername ALL= NOPASSWD: path/to/crclient`

save and exit

Comment: if this answer helps/is the answer then press the checkmark thingy underneath the voting arrows

Comment: Code is running perfectly but while running getting this error   [ > ./cyberrom.sh: line 1: !/bin/sh: No such file or directory ] and after that its asking user name but its worked and i also added in startup and reboot but is not prompting that screen

Comment: I see what happened :P
Add # before !/bin/sh
so you get
#!/bin/sh

Comment: I forgot to add that to the code, my bad!

Comment: after adding #!/bin/sh now its working and is it possible to add password to same code??

Comment: that the user him/herself puts in? if so, post the command with the string the user adds for a passcode

Comment: ok lemme phrase it this way,

sudo ./crclient -u username -i eth0 

that's the command, but how does one enter the password?

sudo ./crclient -u username -i eth0 -p password?

Comment: what im asking is, what command do they input if they add a password

Comment: wait... let me chk once with configuration file

Comment: yep, yep yep yep!

Comment: forget about password thing that i managed with configuration file now everything is perfect expect startup thing so need some more help

Comment: did you do this one?

`xterm -e "sh /path/to/your/script.sh"`

or

`gnome-terminal -x "sh /path/to/script.sh"`


the xterm one only works with the xterm program, the gnome-terminal one is the one you need if you don't have xterm

Comment: i already did  gnome-terminal its working perfectly but that screen i want add in a startup

Comment: what screen? can you eloberate?

Comment: its asking user name

Comment: Hold on, I am confused at this point, what it should do is open a terminal asking for the username, you enter your username and then it start the program, does it do that?

Comment: yes my program is working when i entered user name.. but now i want that code to run in startup basically i want pop up that code  so whenever restart my system it will prompt me with that code like pop up

Comment: just follow the tutorial I posted, or does it not work?

Comment: its not worked i already try

Comment: Is it right or wrong ??

name :  abc
command :  .sh file path
comment : xyz

Comment: no its just example

Comment: i see, you need to do this :)

name: abc
command:  gnome-terminal -x "sh /path/to/script.sh"
comment: Testoroonie

Comment: ok look at the tutorial i am editing it

Comment: Sry for the late reply..i have checked when i was run the script normally ./ it will ask me 3 steps 1 user name 2 sudo password 3 cyberrom password  and its working 100% but after reboot in startup showing only 2 steps 1 username and sudo password so i think there is any startup command issue

Comment: ok try this
change `Exec=/path/to/my/script.sh`
to 
`Exec=gnome-terminal -x "/path/to/my/script.sh"`

Comment: also if you want you can remove the sudo password :)

Comment: no its not working via Exec=gnome-terminal command even its not working stratup as well

Comment: Exec=gnome-terminal  command via terminal its working perfectly

Comment: ok question, do you mind installing xterm?

Comment: xterm is alredy installed in my system

Comment: ok ok :) go back to the gui startup menu like in the tutorial and as command do `xterm -e "sh /path/to/script.sh"`

Comment: this command is not working it will ask only username and sudo password

Comment: hrm.... then i do not know anymore, i am sorry my friend :/

Comment: Its ok #patrick thnks for your help... thank you so much once again

Comment: no problem that's why this site is here

Comment: yes you are right :)

Comment: also, if you wish to know more about shell script and bash scripts, start expirementing with it!, that's what i did like 2 months ago and now i got multiple scripts on github and even one to fully install a raspberry pi to a thin client!