# Ubuntu replaces wallpaper on startup

Tags: unity, bash, scripts, desktop-background

### Background

I have a small script that changes my wallpaper to a random image:

```
#!/bin/bash
feh --randomize --bg-fill /home/USERNAME/Pictures/wallpapers/*
```

It works like a charm, so I decided to add it to the startup applications, like in this question:

- [how to run a specific command via a bash script and add in to a startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804340/how-to-run-a-specific-command-via-a-bash-script-and-add-in-to-a-startup)

### Problem

Everything works fine except for one problem:

- On start up, the wallpaper is changed via the script, as expected. Then, seconds after, Ubuntu takes over and replaces that wallpaper with the default one.

### Question

How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why Wallpaper is Replaced

Long story short, when you have desktop icons enabled, that essentially enables Nautilus to create the Desktop "window" with all the file and folder icons *and manage background*. `feh` works with raw `X11` desktop, i.e. bare bones, where no icons exist. So there's two potential solutions: one is to rely on Ubuntu's settings for background, or two - disable desktop icons. One can also make a script to launch both `feh` and alter Ubuntu desktop settings, but that's redundant in my opinion. Whichever way you decide to go is up to you

#### Disabling/Enabling icons

This can be done via `gsettings org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` to disable and `org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` to enable. Once that's done Nautilus won't manage your desktop, hence won't set the background picture

#### Ubuntu Wallpaper Settings

Aside from obvious GUI methods, one can use `gsettings` command to set the wallpaper.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/my_user/Pictures/cool_wallpaper.png
```

Of course, previously mentioned caveat applies - the desktop icons have to be enabled.

#### Alternative to Your Script

I have noticed that you are trying to set a random wallpaper from a folder.  You don't have to rely on `feh` for that. In the past, I've written two scripts to do this task. One written as [bash script](https://askubuntu.com/a/744470/295286) and another one as [Python script](https://askubuntu.com/a/863103/295286). Both scripts work with Ubuntu's `gsettings` and alter the desktop wallpaper without disabling icons. Personally, I'd suggest the Python one as it is more polished.